# Implementing CORS in Google App Engine server

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile, cors

I have an app on `GAE` that checks if a user is logged in to Google using the Google Users Service.If the user isn't logged in, it is supposed to redirect to the login page from Google.

Here is the code that attempts to do this:

```
class RegistrationHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        username = self.request.get(user.nickname())
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        member = Member.get_by_id('username')
        if member:
            self.response.write("A member with that id already exists")
        else:
            m_username=self.request.get('username')
            m_name=self.request.get('name')
            member = Member(id=m_username, username=m_username, member_name=m_name)
            member.put()
        if callback:
            self.response.write(callback + '(' + member.toJSON() + ')')
        else:
            self.response.write(member.toJSON())
    else:
         self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

However,when i make the request from my `jQuery Mobile` app, i get the error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:18090/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'    

header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is  

therefore not allowed access.
```

So i did a little research and found that this was caused by a `CORS` failure.
So i dug further and found some information on [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html) website which says to use this piece of code:

```
class CORSEnabledHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
     self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
     self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
     self.response.out.write(self.dump_csv())
```

on the server.
Being a newbie, i am not exactly sure how to implement this.The other suggestions which are in `javascript` are a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what the website outlines is sufficient then add the line

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

inside your post handler and inside your `if user` condition.

Of course this needs to be done in conjunction with the appropriate javascript at the client end.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Thanks Tim,have you got any idea on the Google url i should use? or should i just copy the one from the sign-in page?

Comment: The URL should be whatever you `RegistrationHandler` is mapped too.